# Accessing variable inside of forEach callback

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to access a variable whose purpose is to aggregate records seen so far inside of the callback provided to forEach. Something like this:

```
var myfn = function() {
    var aggregate_val = [];
    someObj.someFunction(
        arg1,
        arg2,
        (function() {
            ....
            some_array.forEach(function(e) {
                this.aggregate_val.push(e.some_property);
            }, this);
        }).bind(this)
    );
}
```

Why shouldn't this work?

Comment: why are you using this ?

Comment: @AhmedEid PTAL. I have updated the problem a bit.

Comment: @ibp73 Ahmed and Pavan are right. `aggregate_val` is a variable, not a property, there's no reason to pass `this`. It can simply be accessed directly through closure.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `this` to refer to the array `aggregate_val`. Try this code:

```
var myfn = function() {
  var aggregate_val = [];
  some_array.forEach(function(e) {
    aggregate_val.push(e.some_property);
  });
  console.log(some_array) // I added this so you can see the value of some_array
}
```

Comment: @ibp73: The solution is the same.